# Rack space cloud files - download a file in a private container using PHP SDK

Tags: file, rackspace-cloud, rackspace-cloudfiles

I would like to download a private file (a file in a private container) from rackspace cloud files just using the api.

I think it's possible to create a temporary hash/key, then redirect my logged user to an URL with this hash.

Is it possible?

How could I achieve this using the PHP SDK?

Best regards!